# How do I disable the default behavior of react-select with isMulti from displaying the selected option in the text box

Tags: react-select, react-state

I am trying to use the react-select component which works fine though I would like do disable the default behavior of it displaying the selected options in the text box.

I have tried adding the `hideSelectedOptions={true}` to it but this does not have any effect on it

```
<Select
        closeMenuOnSelect={true}
        components={animatedComponents}
        options={data}
        styles={colourStyles}
        name={name}
        onChange={(option, e) => change(option, e)}
        isMulti={multiple}
        defaultValue={value?.label !== '' ? value : null}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        hideSelectedOptions={true} 
      />
```